# Copy a list of Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an issue with a formula I have no idea which one or how to make it.

I have a 'Master' tab which is essentially going to display all the customers from the 'Mon' 'Tues' (through to Saturday) tabs. My issue is, the number of customers on any given day can vary so one week on Monday, we could have 10 customers, the next Monday it could be 17.

I would like a formula that will copy all the cells with text/numbers in from A3 down to the last cell from that list, then continue the same for Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday.

I have tried IF formulas but am aware this would get exponentially larger the further down it goes and would not work.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a good and easy solution for that. Probably you need to write a macro to do it.

Comment: Yes, I have realised that, I decided to take the high road and record a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=If(isblank(A1),"",A!)` and that will return all of the cell that have names entered.